# Как получить цвет пикселя на который нажал пользователь picturebox? (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms

Мне нужно получить цвет пикселя, на который нажал пользователь на Bitmap. Делаю я это в событии MouseClick вот так:

```
var rgb = bitmap.GetPixel(e.X, e.Y).ToArgb(); 
pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(rgb));
pictureBox.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(rgb);
```

Но picturebox просто становится прозрачным, а pen не рисует. Как быть? Может, дело в событии, или rgb должен быть другим?

Comment: Недостаточно данных. Этот битмап размещен на пикчабоксе? Как именно? Для чего вы создаете перо? Рисуете прямо на контроле (пикчабоксе) или на битмапе? Вы поняли, что я писал в другом вашем вопросе: фон контрола не имеет никакого отношения к картинке, размещенной на этом контроле. PS: приведите _больше_ кода.

Answer (score 0):

```
GetPixel (int x, int y);
```

Где х и у - координаты точки,куда кликнул пользователь